# Select specific items from a random list

Tags: c#

I want to select some items in a random list of elements.

I think I'm not clear enough, then here the code :

```
int numberToken;
List<List<int>> arr = new List<List<int>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    List<int> row = new List<int>()
    {
        1, 2, 3, 4
    };

    arr.Add(row);
}

foreach (List<int> row in arr)
{
    foreach (int _case in row)
    {
        // Display the multidimensional list

        Random randomToken = new Random();

        // Put random numbers in the multidimensional list.
        // The random numbers will be between 1 and 4.
        numberToken = randomToken.Next(1, 5);
        Console.Write(" " + numberToken + " ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

So I want to select each numbers of this list and put them in a variable. Like put all the numbers 1 in a variable, all the numbers 2. I'm also trying to put the numbers of the list arr in the randomToken randomly, but I don't really know how to do that.

Thanks a lot for your help ! Tell me if I'm not clear enough.

Comment: Yes, very unclear. Please format code nicely and add sample of expected output.

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to do. Do you want to shuffle the lists, or select a single item from each...?

Comment: Yes it is unclear. Also instantiate the random object outside the loop and reuse it within the loop.